# 'Select as default' not working - Juno

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files, files

I am unable to set default application for images and text. I have to open files using 'open with' every time. E.g. Sublime is set as default for text files in settings, yet it asks for default application.

Comment: Please wait for the updated (fixed) version. Voting to close down as it can't be solved here by answers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a known bug and probably will be fixed soon

https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/836